# In an ELF executable what sections can pointers be stored in?

Tags: linux, executable, elf

Which sections(.data, .rodata, .bss, etc) can be used for storing pointers in an ELF executable on Linux, and other ELF supporting operating system?

Edit:
by pointers I am referring to the C style pointers like
`void* pointer = some_address;`

Comment: You should define what do you mean by pointers in your question, since it is much more complex (in the context of ELF) that what you believe.

Comment: Your edit does not means much (hence my downvote). You really should read more about ELF. Start with its wikipage on [Executable & Linkable Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) & [Relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29). Read Levine's book [*Linkers and Loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which sections(.data, .rodata, .bss, etc) can be used for storing pointers in an ELF executable

Is this homework? If not, what are you really trying to achieve?

Each of `.data`, `.rodata` and `.bss` can store pointers. So can `.text`. `ELF` allows for arbitrarily named sections, so a full list of sections that can store pointers is impossible (because it's infinite).

Comment: This is not homework. I intend to find out if pointers can be stored read only mainly but then I decided to ask about the other two sections as well

Comment: @zeitue So now you know that pointers can be *anywhere*. In what way does that help you? What are you *really* trying to achieve?

Comment: it means I'm going to have to make compensation for that. I'm trying to achieve a universal format and I've found pointers to be my main issue.
Thanks for the answer